My Google oauth2 client id does not appear in Google API Console
I have an iOS app that has been successfully using Google Sign-in since 2018. However, its client id does not appear in the Credentials page of the API Console. I believe I'm looking at the right Google API account, because during Google Sign-in, it shows what Google account the app developer is associated with, and it's this one. Is there anywhere else my client id would be hiding?
There are 2 other oauth client ids on the Credentials page, however one is for Android and one is for web, and neither of them match anyways.

It looks like the Google Console is buggy. Apparently I had accidentally created a new project with the same name, and all project selections were incorrectly keyed off of project name rather than project id. Thus, my original project was "shadowed" and essentially disappeared from almost all of Google Console and was unselectable. https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager does properly key off project id, so I eventually found the two identically named projects there, renamed one, and suddenly everything worked.
I've reported this bug to Google.
